# Не получается добавить точку на QGraphicsScene

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Нашел [код](http://www.cyberforum.ru/qt/thread1150928.html) на c++, попробовал переделать на python, но что-то делаю не так. При выполнении данного кода прога вылетает.

```
    self.item = QGraphicsItem(self)
    self.item.setPos(QPointF(20,10))
    self.scene.addItem(self.item)
```

Comment: А что конкретно у вас не получается? Ошибка или что то?

Comment: Ошибка, при выполнении

Comment: Какая ошибка? Пишите подробнее в вопросе для общего понимания

Comment: Прога закрывается без ошибки

Comment: попробуйте с `python -X faulthandler` запускать, что Си стек напечатать при возникновении ошибки.

Comment: `TypeError: PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem represents a C++ abstract class and can
not be instantiated`

Comment: @santos_q, это значит что класс QGraphicsItem абстрактный и нельзя создавать его объекты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scene = QGraphicsScene()
scene.addEllipse(20, 10, 1, 1)
self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)
```

Comment: 1) Можно добавить что элемент "точка" нет, зато его можно заменить эллипсом с маленьким размером. 2) И добавить еще вариант добавления элемента: `item = QGraphicsEllipseItem(20, 10, 1, 1)` `self.scene.addItem(item)` 3) Добавить ссылку на документацию: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsellipseitem.html